# Dask_ml import error: No module named 'numpy.testing'

Tags: dask

I'm trying to execute the following:

```
from dask_ml.cluster import SpectralClustering

def get_closest_rows(shot, df, hash_result, n = 10):

    nn = SpectralClustering(n=n, metric='manhattan')

    # Fit the model to the hash_result
    nn.fit(hash_result)

    # Compute distances and indices of 10 closest rows for the specified row
    distances, indices = nn.kneighbors(shot)

    # Combine distances and indices into a single DataFrame
    closest_rows = pd.DataFrame({
        'row_id': df.index.values[indices[0]],
        'distance': distances[0]
    })

    # Remove the row itself from the list of closest rows
    closest_rows = closest_rows[closest_rows['row_id'] != shot.index[0]]

    # Sort by distance and keep only the 10 closest rows
    closest_rows = closest_rows.sort_values('distance').head(10)

    return closest_rows
```

This is the output:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ModuleNotFoundError                       Traceback (most recent call last)
Input In [290], in <cell line: 1>()
----> 1 from dask_ml.cluster import SpectralClustering
      3 def get_closest_rows(shot, df, hash_result, n = 10):
      5     nn = SpectralClustering(n=n, metric='manhattan')

File ~/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/dask_ml/__init__.py:4, in <module>
      1 from pkg_resources import DistributionNotFound, get_distribution
      3 # Ensure we always register tokenizers
----> 4 from dask_ml.model_selection import _normalize
      6 __all__ = []
      8 try:

File ~/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/dask_ml/model_selection/__init__.py:6, in <module>
      1 """Utilities for hyperparameter optimization.
      2 
      3 These estimators will operate in parallel. Their scalability depends
      4 on the underlying estimators being used.
      5 """
----> 6 from ._hyperband import HyperbandSearchCV
      7 from ._incremental import IncrementalSearchCV, InverseDecaySearchCV
      8 from ._search import GridSearchCV, RandomizedSearchCV, check_cv, compute_n_splits

File ~/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/dask_ml/model_selection/_hyperband.py:10, in <module>
      7 from warnings import warn
      9 import numpy as np
---> 10 from sklearn.utils import check_random_state
     12 from ._incremental import BaseIncrementalSearchCV
     13 from ._successive_halving import SuccessiveHalvingSearchCV

File ~/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/sklearn/__init__.py:82, in <module>
     80 from . import _distributor_init  # noqa: F401
     81 from . import __check_build  # noqa: F401
---> 82 from .base import clone
     83 from .utils._show_versions import show_versions
     85 __all__ = [
     86     "calibration",
     87     "cluster",
   (...)
    128     "show_versions",
    129 ]

File ~/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/sklearn/base.py:17, in <module>
     15 from . import __version__
     16 from ._config import get_config
---> 17 from .utils import _IS_32BIT
     18 from .utils._tags import (
     19     _DEFAULT_TAGS,
     20     _safe_tags,
     21 )
     22 from .utils.validation import check_X_y

File ~/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/sklearn/utils/__init__.py:28, in <module>
     26 from ..exceptions import DataConversionWarning
     27 from .deprecation import deprecated
---> 28 from .fixes import np_version, parse_version
     29 from ._estimator_html_repr import estimator_html_repr
     30 from .validation import (
     31     as_float_array,
     32     assert_all_finite,
   (...)
     40     check_scalar,
     41 )

File ~/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/sklearn/utils/fixes.py:20, in <module>
     18 import scipy.sparse as sp
     19 import scipy
---> 20 import scipy.stats
     21 from scipy.sparse.linalg import lsqr as sparse_lsqr  # noqa
     22 import threadpoolctl

File ~/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/scipy/stats/__init__.py:485, in <module>
      1 """
      2 .. _statsrefmanual:
      3 
   (...)
    480 
    481 """
    483 from ._warnings_errors import (ConstantInputWarning, NearConstantInputWarning,
    484                                DegenerateDataWarning, FitError)
--> 485 from ._stats_py import *
    486 from ._variation import variation
    487 from .distributions import *

File ~/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/scipy/stats/_stats_py.py:37, in <module>
     35 from numpy import array, asarray, ma
     36 from numpy.lib import NumpyVersion
---> 37 from numpy.testing import suppress_warnings
     39 from scipy.spatial.distance import cdist
     40 from scipy.ndimage import _measurements

ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'numpy.testing'
```

After running the following, as seen in other posts that fixes the problem:

```
!pip install -U numpy
!pip install -U pandas
!pip install -U scipy

Requirement already satisfied: numpy in /home/norhther/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages (1.24.2)
Requirement already satisfied: pandas in /home/norhther/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages (1.5.3)
Requirement already satisfied: python-dateutil>=2.8.1 in /home/norhther/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages (from pandas) (2.8.2)
Requirement already satisfied: numpy>=1.20.3 in /home/norhther/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages (from pandas) (1.24.2)
Requirement already satisfied: pytz>=2020.1 in /home/norhther/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages (from pandas) (2021.3)
Requirement already satisfied: six>=1.5 in /home/norhther/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages (from python-dateutil>=2.8.1->pandas) (1.16.0)
Requirement already satisfied: scipy in /home/norhther/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages (1.10.1)
Requirement already satisfied: numpy<1.27.0,>=1.19.5 in /home/norhther/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages (from scipy) (1.24.2)
```

In many posts it says that its some inconsistency between numpy and scipy, however I have updated versions. Also I'm running it on anaconda, using python 3.9 for this. Is anything else that could I try?

Comment: How did you  build your Python environment in the first place?

Comment: @GuillaumeEB I just installed it using `conda install -c conda-forge dask-ml`

Comment: Well, I just installed a new Conda environment using `conda create -n daskml -c conda-forge python=3.9 dask-ml`, and in this environment your code worked fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that the problem is that, at some point in your life, you have installed scipy using pip with the flag --user. Indeed, as you may see from your logs, all the libraries are stored in `~/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages` beside scipy which is in `~/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/scipy`.

Unfortunately, whatever you install with `pip --user` goes in your `.local` directory which comes first when Python searches for packages.

Just remove the `~/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages` dir (or rename it to be safe) and the problem should be solved.